# PyQT5 different view on OS and Linux

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I created a python program that uses PyQT5, but looking at the displayed windows on Mac OS X and Linux then they differentiate quite a bit.

Here is the MAC OS X window

[image]

And here is the Linux version:

[image]

As you can see, the alignment of the tabs and the size/alignment of single lineedits is quite different. I understand that the rendering of the window depends on the underlying operating system, but is there any way to force the system to produce a similar output for all, e.g.:

- Put the tabs to the very left
- Make Lineedits be window width (or whatever size they were set to)

Comment: The way you use OS is very confusing. It usually means any operating system in general, while you seem to be using it for a specific one by Apple, named macOS, formerly Mac OS X.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was referring to Mac OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt5 has a platform-independent style plugin, `fusion`. Set the application to use this style, and it will look exactly the same on all platforms.

You can do this either by using Python code, calling `QApplication.setStyle()`, with an instance of `QFusionStyle`; or by setting the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` environment variable to `fusion`; or by passing `-style fusion` as command line arguments to the application.

It is a decent style in my opinion, however, it doesn't feel entirely "native" anywhere.